# javascript - how to take selected element from function and pass it through as a parameter of another function

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

I have been trying for days upon weeks with trying to build a personal library without jQuery for my school club, and so far I am hitting a rut when it comes to passing through an element or objects through to another function. The notation I am trying for is this :

```
CC(function(){
    CC('id:wrapper').set('html','Hello World!');
});
```

That is my test code, and the library looks as it does below:

```
    "use strict";

    var CC = function () {
        var args = arguments[0] || {};
        if(typeof args === "object") {
            args = args || {};
        }
        else if(typeof args === "function") {
        args = arguments[0];
        return window.onload = args;
    }
    else if(typeof args !== "object" || typeof args !== "function") {
        var elem = get(args);
        return elem;
    }
};

CC({
    //Can only be done once. Will return TypeError because '$' won't exist afterward
    noConflict : function (name) {
        name = new CC();
        return name;
    }
});
//The way to modify things
CC.mod = CC.prototype = {};
CC.extend = CC.mod.extend = function () {
    var args = arguments[0] || {};
    var target = get(args);
    return target;
};
CC.mod.extend({
    //Use psuedo types to set specific values (required)
    set : function(type, value) {
        return set(this.target, type, value);
    }
});
//General get function to get selectors, generate functions, or return values
function get() {
    var args = arguments[0] || {};
    //Check if the argument is a function
    //If it is, return the function on page load
    if (typeof args === "function") {
        return window.onload = args;
    }
    //Check argument type
    if(typeof args !== "object") {
        args = arguments[0];
        return args;
    }
    else {
        args = {};
        return args;
    }
    //Check if args has an elem psuedo
    if(args.indexOf("id:") > -1 || args.indexOf("class:") > -1 || args.indexOf("tag:") > -1) {
        var target = args;
        //Run id psuedo
        if(target.indexOf("id:") > -1) {
            target = target.replace('id:','');
            console.log(target);
            return document.getElementById(target);
        }
        //Run class psuedo
        else if(target.indexOf("class:") > -1) {
            target = target.replace('class:','');
            console.log(target);
            return document.getElementsByClassName(target);
        }
        //Run tag psuedo
        else if(target.indexOf("tag:") > -1) {
            target = target.replace('class:','');
            console.log(target);
            return document.getElementsByTagName(target);
        }
    }
    //Check if args is not null
    //If not, then return args value
    if(args !== null) {
        return args.value;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
//General function to set things for elements
function set(elem, property, value) {
    //If the element provided is part of getting an element
    //If it is, run the psuedo checker
    if(elem.indexOf("id:") > -1 || elem.indexOf("class:") > -1 || elem.indexOf("tag:") > -1) {
        elem = get(elem);
        //Rerun the set() function to set properties and values
        set(elem, property, value);
    }
    //If not, then run the type psuedo checker
    else {
        //Check if style
        if(property.indexOf("css:") > -1 || property.indexOf("style:") > -1) {
            //Check for the independent types
            if(property.indexOf("css:") > -1) {
                property = property.replace('css:','');
                return elem.style[property] = value;
            }
            else if(property.indexOf("style:") > -1) {
                property = property.replace('style:','');
                return elem.style[property] = value;
            }
        }
        //Check if attribute
        else if(property.indexOf("attr:") > -1) {
            property = property.replace('attr:','');
            return elem.setAttribute(property, value);
        }
        //Check if html
        else if(property.indexOf("html") > -1) {
            return elem.innerHTML = value;
        }
        //To add more, just add another else if(condition...) {Code} statement
        //Condition must be defined in psuedo selectors
        //Condition must be property.indexOf("selector:" > -1)
        //return statement must consist of a return value from the value     parameter
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to get my methods to pass through correctly and I don't know how to get my methods to apply to the element in the `CC('id:wrapper')` code. I already have the 'psuedo selector' made to get rid of the `id:` code. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I definitely congratulate you on the effort you've put in, but why would you want to have to redo everything that jQuery (or another library like MooTools or Zepto) has been doing for years?

Comment: It gives me a sort of learning experience for objects, and I wanted to implement a new way of selecting elements. I know that it works, I just can't pass it through the way I wanted to. Also, I am trying to do this in a lot fewer lines of code than jQuery is. They have a lot of lines of code, and I have found many to be kind of unnecessary. I am trying to shorten into a compact yet extendable library. Make functions in my own little way

Comment: Trust me, if jquery could lesson their code without sacrificing something they would. It's why they go through a minimizer

Answer (score 1):

You've posted quite some code which I wasn't able to get to work quickly, so I'm not sure if this will help you out.

The basic idea is that your `CC` method will always have to return an object with a `set` method. If there's no element with `id="wrapper"`, you'll have to figure out a way to handle exceptions.

You can use `bind` to create a new function from an earlier defined function with a pre-bound `this` context and pre-filled in arguments.

A simplified example:

```js
var CC = function(query) {
  return {
    set: set.bind(null, document.querySelector(query))
  };
}


function set(element, attr, val) {
   element.setAttribute(attr, val); 
}


CC("input").set("placeholder", "I was set by js");
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

If you want to do more advanced binding of arguments, I'd suggest you google "Currying". With some code, you can make functions automatically return new functions when called with less arguments than needed.

### What `.bind` does:

The [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method is defined in `Function.prototype`. You can call it on any function you've defined to create a *new* function.

The first argument that goes in to bind, is used as the `this` context in the newly created function. You could, for example, do:

```js
var myDiv = document.querySelector("div");

var logText = function() {
  console.log(this.innerText);  
};

var logDivText = logText.bind(myDiv);
logText(); // Bound to window, logs undefined
logDivText(); // Bound to div, logs text
```

```html
<div>Text in a div</div>
```

Any *other* arguments passed to bind, are automatically passed as arguments. For example:

```js
var sum = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
};

var sum3 = sum.bind(null, 3); // we don't use this, so we don't define it

console.log(sum3(5)); // Prints 8
```

Comment: Your code is amazing, and currying is something I have never tried. I looked it up and it seems like that might just work. When you do `set : set.bind(null, document.querySelector(query))`, what does it do exactly? I think I have a basic idea of what it does, but what exactly is it setting?

Comment: I added some explanation/examples on `bind`.